# XML Data wont display in tables

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a HTML with ajax file, php, xml and xsl files.

I have a dropdown menu in the html file, with a list of different bus routes, when you select your bus route a xmlhttp request is submitted and the bus route data from the xml page is displayed. When you select a new route, the details are displayed and the previous one is gone.

My issue is that the data doesn't appear in the table when selected. The data comes up in text and the table appears under it with empty table rows and columns.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showBus(str){
if (str==""){
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getbus.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}    

</script>
</head>    

<body>

<form>
Select your bus route:
<select name="NUMBER" onchange="showBus(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a Bus:</option>
<option value="120">120</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Bus info will be listed here...</b></div>
</form>        
</body>
</html>

PHP
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("routes.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) {
//Process only element nodes
if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
$y=($x->item($i)->parentNode);
}
} 
}

$BUS=($y->childNodes);

for ($i=0;$i<$BUS->length;$i++) {
//Process only element nodes
if ($BUS->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
echo("<b>" . $BUS->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
echo($BUS->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
echo("<br>");
}
 }

 //Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('routes.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('routes.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);


?> 

XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<TT>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>120</NUMBER>    
<LEAVING>Howth</LEAVING>
<DESTINATION>Dublin Airport</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00, 07:00, 08:10, 9:10, 10:00,
11:25, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:20, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00</TIME>


</BUS>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>15</NUMBER>      
<LEAVING>Clongriffin</LEAVING>
<DESTINATION>Ballyycullen road</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00</TIME>
<TIME>07:00</TIME>
<TIME>08:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:00</TIME>
<TIME>09:30</TIME>
</BUS>
</TT>


XSL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>NUMBER</th>
    <th>LEAVING</th>
    <th>DESTINATION</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
  </tr>

 <xsl:for-each select="TT/BUS/NUMBER">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="LEAVING"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="DESTINATION"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="TIME"/></td>
   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should really use jQuery or any other cross-platform JavaScript library instead of messign with your HTML using just raw Javascript.

Comment: There is a missing curly brace `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` should be `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){`

Comment: @RamRaider I have it in the program, i just forgot it here.

Comment: It looks like the stylesheet isn't being applied correctly - is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you change one piece in your stylesheet this seems to work ok, though it doesn't filter the records as your code suggests it should.

```
change 
<xsl:for-each select="TT/BUS/NUMBER">
to
<xsl:for-each select="TT/BUS">
```

Without using the xsl file, the following php generates effectively the correct output I think.

```
/* We are looking for a bus number given by the GET variable `q` */
$id=$_GET['q'];

/* Create the DOMDocument object */
$dom=new DOMDocument;

/* load your xml file */
$dom->load( 'routes.xml' );

/* find all nodes of type `NUMBER` */
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');

if( $col ){
    /* iterate through the DOMNode collection */
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        /* Search for a node with the given value / id / bus */
        if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $node->nodeValue==$id ) {
            /* We need the parent node so we can iterate through it's children */
            $parent=$node->parentNode;
        }
    }


    /* placeholder into which to generate the output */
    $html=array();
    $html[]='
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>NUMBER</th>
            <th>LEAVING</th>
            <th>DESTINATION</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>';

    /* iterate through the parent's "child nodes." This is the equivalent of the `<xsl:for-each select="TT/BUS">` in the xsl */

    foreach( $parent->childNodes as $node ){
        /* We only want element nodes, add html with value to output array  */
        if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) $html[]='<td>'.$node->nodeValue.'</td>';
    }

    /* Close the row and the table */
    $html[]='</tr></table>';

    /* send back the response to the ajax function */
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
}
```

Using the `xsl` stylesheet the way you were doing meant it was operating on the entire xml document which clearly was not what you intended. It is possible to have passed in a parameter to the xsl which would have allowed you do process the xml file without the intervention of `DOMDocument`, that said though - using the methodology of your initial search for a node in the xml with a matching bus number see the comments above.

Comment: I did have that initially, but it displays all records for each option, not just the record i want.

Comment: @AndreMacnamara Of course, because you're mixing routes.xsl the whole routes.xml at the end of the php file.

Comment: Thats works, but could you explain why it works. Just so i'm not just using code i have no idea why it works

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript error in your main page (just moved the .open and .send functions one } up (fixed in index.html)

Then you are not transforming the BUS you need, but all of the xml file. That is fixed in getbus.php, creating a new document and putting there the appropiate node based on the NAME property.

And in your routes.xsl also were needed to be fixed some selectors. Check it out.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showBus(str){
            if (str==""){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getbus.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    Select your bus route:
    <select name="NUMBER" onchange="javascript:showBus(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a Bus:</option>
        <option value="120">120</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
    </select>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Bus info will be listed here...</b></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

getbus.php

```
<?php

$q = $_GET["q"];

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("routes.xml");

$x = $xml->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');

$nodeNumber = -1;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $x->length - 1; $i++) {
    if ($x->item($i)->nodeType == 1) {
        if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
            $nodeNumber = $i;
        }
    }
}

if ($nodeNumber != -1) {
//Load the XML source
    $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('BUS');

    $newDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $newDoc->appendChild($newDoc->importNode($elements->item($nodeNumber), true));

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('routes.xsl');
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules
    echo $proc->transformToXML($newDoc);
}

?>
```

routes.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>NUMBER</th>
                        <th>LEAVING</th>
                        <th>DESTINATION</th>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="BUS">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="LEAVING"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="DESTINATION"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:for-each select="TIME">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />,
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```